# SWI-Prolog Threads Simple Example

Tags: multithreading, swi-prolog, thread-synchronization

Can someone give a simple example of how to syncronize a multi-threaded prolog program.

I had gone through the manual but there are no examples to explain how to use.

Comment: Try the example on this page: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=threadsync

Comment: Note on the previous comment: there is a typo in the example. retractall(address(Id, _)) should be retractall(address_db(Id, _)).

Comment: At StackOverflow, if a question is worht asking, it's worth answering! When you get 15 or more reputation, please come back and post your answer. The world wants to know. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer